# How to check if a _bstr_t contains (similar to str.find) a string

Tags: c++, windows, string, visual-c++, bstr

I am new to `_bstr_t`'s and still trying to get the hang of it. I was trying to check whether a particular string `x` is contained anywhere within the bstring. Something I would normally do like;

```
String x = "hello";
String example = "You! hello there";
...
if (example.find(x) != string::npos) {
...
```

Just for the record the intended platform is windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to use `_bstr_t`.  Use the `BSTR` type.

Next, read [Eric's Complete Guide to BSTR Semantics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/12/52976.aspx).

Lastly, you can use the BSTR in native code the way you would a normal character array in *most* cases.

```
BSTR bstr = SysAllocString(L"FooBarBazQux");
if (wcsstr(bstr, L"Bar") != NULL) {
  // Found it! Do something.
} else {
  // Not there.
}
SysFreeString(bstr);
```

[MSDN for wcsstr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9da80kz.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the help, however the compiler does not seem to like something, `error C2665: 'wcsstr' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types` ... `const wchar_t *wcsstr(const wchar_t *,const wchar_t *)` ... `wchar_t *wcsstr(wchar_t *,const wchar_t *)`

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code.  Could be a `const` issue?  You can always ask a new question with your new code.

Comment: Disagree with the first advice, `BSTR` is a recipe for memory leaks. Equivalent code: `_bstr_t bstr(L"FooBarBazQux"); if (wcsstr(bstr, L"Bar") != NULL) { } else { }`. No SysFreeString needed.

Comment: At least use `CComBSTR` if you're going to make that argument.

Answer (score 1):

Your example appears to be trying to use string::find from STL.  But you specify your variables of type "String" (capitalized).  If you instead did:

```
using namespace std;
string x = "hello";
string example = "You! hello there";
...
```

your example would compile.  Do you actually have a BSTR or _bstr_t that you need to work with that you haven't shown?  Even if so, it's pretty easy to make an std::string from a _bstr_t, and after that you can use STL as you normally would.